# How many ways can n people sit in 7 chairs in a row and not be next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to find the number of ways for any number of people to sit in a row of 7 chairs if no two people sit next to each other.

With the restriction of 7 chairs then the most number of people can be 4 and there is only way that this can be arranged as well as there being no people also being a solution.

I have brute forced it and got that there are 34 ways. How do I get the formula for this however?

ex. x _ x _ _ x _ works but _ x x _ _ _ x does not.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $m$ be the number of people you want to take a sit in $n\geq 2m-1$ places.

If a person fill a sit, the place after him/her must be empty. Let us add one place at the left most position, which must be empty, thus having $n+1\geq 2m$ places.

We can thus model a couple person-empty sit as a symbol P (you have $m$ of these) and an empty space with an E (you have $n-2m$ of these).

To count the number of different sittings of $m$ people you have go count the arrangements of $m$ P symbols and $n+1-2m$ E symbols, which are: $n+1-m\choose m$.

Hence your answer is

$\sum_{2m\leq n+1} {n-m \choose m}$

For $n=7$ you get

${7\choose 1}+{6\choose 2}+{5\choose3}+{4\choose 4}=7+15+10+1=33$ or $34$ if you count also $0$ people.

Answer (score 1):

You can use stars and bars to solve for individual $n$.

For example, take $n=3$.

With $3$ people, there will be $4$ empty chairs. Let those be our stars:

$****$

Now we use $3$ bars for the people (or, what is the same thing, occupied seats). Since they cannot be next to each other, they need to take up $3$ of $5$ spots: the $3$ spots between the stars, and the two spots on either end. So, you have $5 \choose 3$ ways to do this.

It should be easy to see how this generalizes: with $n\leq 4$ people, you have $7-n$ empty chairs, and thus $8-n$ spots for the $n$ people to go, and thus ${8-n}\choose n$ way to place those $n$ people.

So, do this for all $n\leq 4$, and add them all up.